# Form validation if/else with JQuery

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm making a form validation, where all fields should be required and also check if the user "accept terms", and also check if the e-mail is correct. It almost works, this code gives me a response if I haven't entered name/e-mail etc but if I enter this information, it doesn't hide() the .alert. And then doesn't response to the checkbox for terms and "valid e-mail" check. The .alert should also always be "hidden" if there are no "response".

Where does this code fail? Any thoughts?

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault(); // This will prevent the form submission

    var response = ""; 
     $('#submit-holder').find('input').each(function(){
         if ($(this).val() == '') {
         response += ", " + $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html();
         empty_fields = true;     
         }    

         else if ($(this).val() == !'') {
         empty_fields = false;
             $('.alert').hide()  
         }

         else if(empty_fields = true ) {
                    $('.alert').addClass('alert-danger')
                    $('.alert').fadeIn()               
                    $('.error_message').text(response.replace(", ", "You need to fill out: "))
                    message = response.replace(", ", "You need to fill out: ")
                    response_message(message)
         }   

        else if ($('[name="txtEmail"]').length !== 0) {

            var email = $('[name="txtEmail"]').val();

            if(IsEmail(email)==false){
                    message = "The e-mail address you've entered is invalid";
                    response_message(message)
                       //return false;
                   }
            }

           else if($('#user_terms').not(":checked")){ 
           message = "You need to accept the terms and conditions to continue";
           response_message(message)
              //return false;

             } 

         }); 

 if($('#user_terms').is(":checked") && !response) {

  // Send the form

 } 


// Functions:
 function IsEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if(!regex.test(email)) {
       return false;
    }else{
       return true;
    }
  }

function response_message(message) {

    $('.alert').addClass('alert-danger')
    $('.alert').fadeIn()               
    $('.error_message').text(message)
}
```

Comment: else if ($(this).val() == !'') { - looks like a culprit...

Comment: It looks as though you are missing a number of line end semicolons ;

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery form won't validate to success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379864/jquery-form-wont-validate-to-success)

Answer (score 0):

why wont you use a validator plugin.

i use http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: yes i know, but i'm new here.. and i don't have enough permissions/reputation to comment... sorry :(

Comment: It could be good, but I would like not too many "plugins I don't know"

Answer (score 0):

Hi this code will work without errors , but i am not sure about your logic is correct.

```
$("form").submit(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault(); // This will prevent the form submission

    var response = ""; 
     $('#submit-holder').find('input').each(function(){
         if ($(this).val() == '') {
         response += ", " + $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html();
         empty_fields = true;     
         }    

         else if ($(this).val() != '') {
         empty_fields = false;
             $('.alert').hide();  
         }

         else if(empty_fields = true ) {
                    $('.alert').addClass('alert-danger');
                    $('.alert').fadeIn();         
                    $('.error_message').text(response.replace(", ", "You need to fill out: "));
                    message = response.replace(", ", "You need to fill out: ");
                    response_message(message);
         }   

        else if ($('[name="txtEmail"]').length !== 0) {

            var email = $('[name="txtEmail"]').val();

            if(IsEmail(email)==false){
                    message = "The e-mail address you've entered is invalid";
                    response_message(message);
                       //return false;
                   }
            }

           else if($('#user_terms').not(":checked")){ 
           message = "You need to accept the terms and conditions to continue";
           response_message(message);
              //return false;

             } 

         }); 

 if($('#user_terms').is(":checked") && !response) {

  // Send the form

 } 


// Functions:
 function IsEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    if(!regex.test(email)) {
       return false;
    }else{
       return true;
    }
  }

function response_message(message) {

    $('.alert').addClass('alert-danger');
    $('.alert').fadeIn();          
    $('.error_message').text(message);
}
```