# JQuery form won't validate to success

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I'm having problem to "get pass" the validation of my form validator, it stops and won't start to process. When it should be processed it gives me "You need to fill out: "

What could be wrong?

[Fidde](http://jsfiddle.net/SBYQ5/4/)

Jquery:

```
  $("form").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // This will prevent the form submission
  var response = ""; 
  var missing = ""; 
  $('#submit-holder').find('input').each(function(){
     if ($(this).val() == '') {
     missing += $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').html() + " | ";
     empty_fields = true;     
     missing_fields = true;
     }    

     else if ($(this).val() != '') {
     empty_fields = false;
         $('.alert').hide();  
     }

     }); 

     response += "* <strong>You need to fill out:</strong> " + missing;

     if(!$('#user_terms').is(':checked')) 
     { 
     response += "<br>* You need to accept the terms and conditions to continue";
     } 

     var email = $('[name="txtEmail"]').val();

     if(IsEmail(email)==false){
          valid_email = false;
          response += "<br><strong>* The e-mail address you've entered is invalid</strong>";
     }

     response_message(response);

     if(!missing_fields && valid_email !== false &&     $('#user_terms').is(":checked")) {

     $('.alert').hide()


 }
    });

// Functions:
 function IsEmail(email) {
 var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-\+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
 if(!regex.test(email)) {
   return false;
 }else{
   return true;
 }
}

function response_message(response) {
$('.alert').addClass('alert-danger');
$('.alert').fadeIn();          
$('.error_message').html(response);
}
```

Comment: Did you read this code? What behaviour do you expect from it?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Any errors in the console?

Comment: I expect that efter this if() the form should process and .hide() the .alert => `(!missing_fields && valid_email !== false &&     $('#user_terms').is(":checked")) {`

Comment: `$('#submit-holder').find('input').length` is equal to 0, to begin with...
Check the selector.

Comment: I've tried to debug it with console but it doesn't give any errors so I think there is a "logic-fail" but can't figure out the flow

Comment: `#submit-holder` DOM does not exist

Comment: You cannot have debugged hard. I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: missing_fields is not defined "

Comment: @Saravanan Thanks, i missed it in the fiddle, thanks for notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More errors

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/EePgp/)

```
if (missing) response += "* <strong>You need to fill out:</strong> " + missing;



if (IsEmail(email) == false) {
    valid_email = false;
    response += "<br><strong>* The e-mail address you've entered is invalid</strong>";
}
else valid_email = true; // missing

response_message(response);

if (!missing_fields && valid_email && $('#user_terms').is(":checked")) {
```

Comment: Thanks for a really nice code! It works like a charm!

Comment: Incredible someone downvotes without comments!

Answer (score 0):

The is a selector error.

Here is the working version: http://jsfiddle.net/SBYQ5/18/

Just replace `$('#submit-holder').find('input').each(function () {` with `$('form').find('input').each(function () {`

Or - aternatively - add `submit-holder` as form id.

Moreover, you were missing some var declarations.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't process. When form is submitted,         alert(json) should be fired.

Comment: Checkout my answer, I've updated it ;-)
Now it should work well

Answer (score 0):

When you are checking for email by calling the function, you are checking if its not valid, you are setting valid_email to false. When email is valid, you are not setting it to true.

You can use either

```
if(IsEmail(email)==false){
  valid_email = false;
  response += "<br><strong>* The e-mail address you've entered is invalid</strong>";
}
else {
  valid_email = true;
}


Or

valid_email = true;
if(IsEmail(email)==false){
  valid_email = false;
  response += "<br><strong>* The e-mail address you've entered is invalid</strong>";
}
```